# how to get the comment ID in the front end when the REPLY button is clicked?

Tags: jquery, ajax, comments, comments-template

I think I might be able to parse the URL for the `replytocom` parameter and get the comment ID from that. However, it would mean that my plugin would not be fully compatible with other plugins that can remove this parameter (most notably *Yoast SEO*).  Plus, it feels a bit hacky. Is there another way?

Endgoal: I need that comment ID to use in an AJAX request - to fetch data (such as the comment thread depth) so that I can display custom data in the front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are few ideas:

- It's possible to inject custom HTML or data attributes via the [`comment_reply_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comment_reply_link/) filter, but I think it would be better to keep it unobtrusive.
- One could try to get the comment parent value from the reply comment form:

  ```
  <input type='hidden' name='comment_parent' id='comment_parent' value='0' />
  ```

  after it has been updated with the corresponding value.
- Another approach would be to scan for IDs in the HTML of the comments list:

  Generated by the `Walker_Comment::html5_comment()`:

  ```
  <li id="comment-34" class="comment even thread-even depth-1">
      <article id="div-comment-34" class="comment-body">
      ... cut...
  ```

  Generated by the `Walker_Comment::comment()`:

  ```
  <li class="comment even thread-even depth-1 parent" id="comment-34">
      <div id="div-comment-34" class="comment-body">
      ... cut...
  ```

  One could e.g. search for both cases, but it's possible for the user to override these with a custom output.

  Also note the `depth` information here.
- One could try to parse the `onclick` attribute of the *replyto* link:

  ```
  onclick='return addComment.moveForm( "div-comment-34", "34", "respond", "123" )'
  ```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your final option (parsing onclick) and it worked. I chose it because it's the easiest for me to implement. I'll post the code.  However, I'm using AJAX to get the parent ID whilst your other suggestions tell me that I can get the parent ID directly so I might try your 2nd suggestion too.

Comment: Great, thanks for sharing your implementation. Regarding suggestion #4, it might be more stable to parse out the second input parameter of `addComment.moveForm()`, as the `div-comment-` part of the first input parameter can change. Regarding suggestion #2, this is the same ID as in e.g. #4. So are you looking for the grandparent ID? @woodduck

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the IDs in suggestion #1 and #'4 being the same. In your examples, they are 0 and 34, respectively.  I need just the parent. EDIT: Are you referring to the 'respond' value (123 in your example)? I'm not sure what that is, but can't be the parent - wouldn't the parent ID be < 34?

Comment: When we press the "Reply" link, then the hidden `comment_parent` input is assigned the value of 34 by javascript, the same ID value as in #4. I was then just wondering what you meant by *"However, I'm using AJAX to get the parent ID"*, I guess you want to fetch the parent for the comment  with ID=34. (grandparent of the comment we're about to write)  No didn't meant the respond value, that's the current post ID @woodduck

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the clarification. Yes, I want the grandparent then. For a while I thought that WP puts this ID in the hidden field attributes, so that I could parse that directly instead of using AJAX to look it up.  But it's fine as it is. gets the job done.

Comment: aha ok. I guess you could also try to get the info from the DOM tree, instead of using ajax. Maybe using clever find/parent/... selectors with jQuery. There's e.g. *parent* class added to parent comment nodes, but it might be filtered out by the users. But it looks like you've got a working solution - Bestu of luck ;-) @woodduck

Answer (score 1):

This is my implementation of [birgire](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/26350/birgire)'s last suggestion (to parse the onclick):

```
jQuery(document).on( 'click', 'a.comment-reply-link', function( event ) {

// THIS PART GETS THE COMMENT ID
var hayStack = jQuery(this).attr('onclick');
var strawA = '"div-comment-';
var strawB = '"';
var tipNeedle = hayStack.lastIndexOf(strawA)+strawA.length;
var hayTruss = hayStack.substring(tipNeedle);
var endNeedle = hayTruss.indexOf(strawB); 
var needle = hayTruss.substring(0, endNeedle);
alert(needle);

// optional: THIS PART LOOKS UP THE PARENT ID (php side not shown)
var datatopost = {
        action: 'my_ajax_hook',
        nonce: ajaxobject.nonce,
        selected_comment_id: needle,
    };
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: ajaxobject.ajaxurl,
    data: datatopost,
    error: function() { // Ajax request has failed
        jQuery('#comment').val('An error has occurred');
    },
    success: function (response) { // Ajax request has succeeded
        if (response.success) {
            // JSON successfully received
            alert(response.data.selected_comment_parent);
        }
    }
}); 
});
```